# Compare model to implementation in Redex

Tags: racket, plt-redex

I'm working on building a model in Redex of a type system that also has a canonical implementation. I would like to use redex-check to fuzz test my model against the actual implementation.

The implementation (with an adapter) can take my abstract syntax, so what I need is a way of passing the term generated by the fuzzer to the implementation. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out [`redex-check`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/redex/The_Redex_Reference.html?q=redex-check#%28form._%28%28lib._redex%2Freduction-semantics..rkt%29._redex-check%29%29), when combined with [`apply-reduction-relation*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/redex/The_Redex_Reference.html?q=apply-reduction-relation*#%28def._%28%28lib._redex%2Freduction-semantics..rkt%29._apply-reduction-relation*%29%29) handles this directly if you can either give redex terms to your actual implementation, or convert them to fit with your implementation.  Your code will look something like this:

```
(redex-check λv e
             (equal? (implementation (convert (term e)))
                     (first (apply-reduction-relation* red (term e)))))
```

Where `implementation` is your implementation, `red` is the reduction relation your model uses, and `convert` converts the term into something your implementation can handle. Also `λv` is your language and `e` is the term in your language you want it to test.

The `first` is simply because `apply-reduction-relation*` returns a list of all possible reductions. If your model is deterministic, this should be a list of length one. (Which you can check by using the following reduction relation instead:

```
(redex-check λv e
             (let ([result (apply-reduction-relation* red (term e))])
               (and (= (length result) 1)
                    (equal? (implementation (convert (term e)))
                            (first result)))))
```

You can see another example of how to use `redex-check` on the tutorial [on the redex home page](http://redex.racket-lang.org/lam-v.html).